# How to set Haskell indentation with Prelude

Tags: prelude, haskell-mode

I'm using Prelude and Haskell mode and trying to set the indentation. The default indentation gives me the following:

```
main = do
  contents <- getContents
  print (sumFile contents)
  where sumFile = sum . map read . words
```

I'd like to have it indented like this:

```
main = do
    contents <- getContents
    print (sumFile contents)
  where sumFile = sum . map read . words
```

I tried to set `M-x customize-option RET haskell-indentation-left-offset`, set the value to 4, chose "Apply and Save" and nothing happened.

How do I fix the indentation? Thanks.

Comment: `haskell-indent-after-keywords` can be used to customize indentation on per-keyword basis, but I can't get it to work with your example.